# bc syntax error BASH

Tags: bash

En el siguiente codigo ejecutado en script :

```
resul=$( echo "$var1>$var2" | bc ) 
if [[ $resul -eq 0 ]]
then echo 'no hay capacidad'
fi
```

Al ejecutar me sale el siguiente mensaje:

```
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
```

Sin hacer correctamente la comparación, las variables están bien definidas.

Answer (score 0):

Revisa que los valores de las variables correspondan con lo esperado, si `bc` indica un error la expresión no es correcta. Para depurar la salida enviada a `bc` puede usarse `echo "$var1>$var2" | tee /dev/fd/2 | bc`. Igualmente, si los valores son enteros puede usarse la condición `-gt` de `[` o `test`, en lugar de `bc`.

Comment: Hola, las variables están correctas y lo que pasa es que quiero comparar números con decimales, de ahí que necesite el comando ```bc```. No he conseguido un cambio en el resultado al depurarlo con tu sugerencia pero muchas gracias por la ayuda!

Comment: Simplemente no pueden ser ambas correctas. Con depurar me refiero solamente a observar en la terminal la salida que genera el comando echo | tee antes del error de bc, qué se muestra?

Comment: me muestra lo siguiente: ```7>19,99
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
no hay capacidad```

Comment: El separador decimal en bc no es coma, sino punto, de ahí el error. Si dicho valor proviene de un archivo puedes transformarlo con `tr , .`

Comment: Hola, Eso es !!!

Comment: Muchas gracias !!